# Can not run tests in APITestCase

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-testing

**Structure of project**

```
proj/
  apps/
    app1/
      ...
      tests.py
    ...
  proj/
```

**tests.py**

```
class UsersTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.get(id=3)
        self.client = APIClient()

    def test_users_list(self):
        ...
```

I run *python manage.py test --settings=proj.settings.local* and see *Ran 0 tests in 0.000s*

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the module as test argument

```
python manage.py test --settings=proj.settings.local apps.app1
```

If it still failed, check if you have `'apps.app1'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'apps' has no attribute '__file__'`

Comment: Did you have `__init__.py` inside `apps` folder?